# Navigator.clipboard.write not working across iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, clipboard

I'm using this little snippet to put text from my web app into the user's clipboard.

```
function copyToClip(str) {
  console.log('Copying to clipboard...', str);
  try {
    console.log('Clipboard API worked...!!!!');
    const blobInput = new Blob([str], {type: 'text/html'});
    const clipboardItemInput = new ClipboardItem({'text/html' : blobInput});
    navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItemInput]);
  } catch (err){
    console.log('Clipboard API FAILED...');
  }
};
```

My web app is mobile-friendly and I want this copy to clipboard function to work on iOS. It does, but only with certain apps. It works for Outlook (for instance) and other browser tabs, but not Apple Messages or LinkedIn. If I use the device's clipboard I can, of course, paste into Messages and LinkedIn.

Are there app-specific permissions behind this? Any way around it? Strange that iOS lets you put something into the clipboard...but then not use it in certain apps.

Appreciations for any help.

With help from Santiago got this working - needed to use plain text in some iOS apps, apparently. Security settings?

```
function copyToClip(str) {
  console.log('Copying to clipboard...', str);
  try {
    console.log('111NeW Clipboard API worked...!!!!');
    var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    if (isMobile) {
      // strip HTML
      alert('Copied plain text to clipboard!');
      console.log('Clipboard on mobile device...strip HTML...');
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = str;
      str = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(str);
    } else {
      const blobInput = new Blob([str], {type: 'text/html'});
      const clipboardItemInput = new ClipboardItem({'text/html' : blobInput});
      navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItemInput]);
      // alert('Copied to clipboard!');
    }
  } catch (err){
    console.log('Clipboard API FAILED...');
  }
};    //  END copyToClip
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is precisely. I wanted to note a few things about the clipboard API in case it helps you. 
1. The `clipboard.write` method is meant for arbitrary data. Since you are specifying HTML for this may be the applications that are giving you trouble don't accept HTML inputs, so it gets filtered. If you are only copying text you could use `clipboard.writeText`.
2. The writeText method in Safari must be called within user gesture event handlers. The write method does not specify that but it might be worth checking if that is an issue also

Comment: Thank you so much for this insight. You were right...although weird that those apps do allow HTML from a user-initiated copy/paste...security, I guess. If you want to write this as an answer I'll accept. I've added my updated code to the question.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `clipboard.write` method is meant for arbitrary data. Since you are specifying HTML for this, maybe the applications that are giving you trouble don't accept HTML inputs, so it gets filtered.

If you are only copying text you could use `clipboard.writeText`.

It's also worth noting that the `clipboard.writeText` method in Safari must be called within user gesture event handlers. The `clipboard.write` method does not specify that but it might be worth checking if that is an issue also.